# Error calling getResources().openRawResource()

Tags: java, android

I have to read a file called `hello.txt` using the following code on java/eclipse/android:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Tokenirzer {
    public String ReadPath () {

        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hello);
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

> The method getResources() is undefined for the type Tokenirzer

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getResources.openRawResource(R.raw.textfile)))

Comment: this is not related to android, or even java. This is OOP 101. Methods belong to Objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResources()` is part of `Context`.  You can use it like that in an `Activity` because it inherits from `Context`.  You need to pass in your activity's Context to use `getResources`.

Comment: any idea in how to paas context or a web page that says how to do so ?

Comment: `public String ReadPath(Context context){ InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.hello);}`  Then in your Activity, `String myString = myTokenirzer.Readpath(this);`.

Comment: insted of using public string ReadPath i use public void ReadPath if using void intead of string should show any ploblem?

Comment: No problem.  That's just the method's return statement.  If you don't need to return a String, then don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Your class `Tokenirzr` does not contain the method `getResources()`.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is old, but I faced similar situation and as per my experience there are 2 solutions. Either the class has to extend Activity() or a reference should be passed from MainActivity()